# Get mat-icon element by icon name in css?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, material-ui

I have the following mat-icons that are generated automatically and for this reason I have no option to add id or class for none of them. The only thing that can be used to differentiate them is their names:

```
<mat-icon role="img">details</mat-icon>
<mat-icon role="img">edit</mat-icon>
<mat-icon role="img">delete</mat-icon>
```

I am wondering if I can set only the icon of delete by using its name without affecting the other mat icons? Is that possible?

Comment: what exactly do you want to "set" on the delete icon?

Comment: Are they distributed throughout the page or, they are at one place.

Comment: @BenzaraTahar It seems to be thinner comparing to the other 2 icons even they are all from the same component (mat-icon). So,  need to make it bold.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal They are at one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
unfortunately No!

**Long answer:**

This code `<mat-icon role="img">delete</mat-icon>` will translates at runtime to something like this

```html
<mat-icon 
class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color"
role="img" aria-hidden="true">delete</mat-icon>
```

as you can see, that doesn't translate to anything useful (class names, data properties..etc) that can be accessed using css selectors. The only piece of information is within the Text element which you cannot use to access an element according to the [specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors).

There have been some thought to include the `:contains()` selector [but it never saw the lights](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#content-selectors).

**BONUS:**

Your last resort is to use some javascript/typescript to achieve this:

```js
let editIcons =[].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('mat-icon'), 
el => el.innerText=="edit");

editIcons.forEach( e => {
e.style.color = "red";
});
```

[image: result]